# Environment variables not loaded when executing command via `ssh` on remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to write a script that executes several commands on a remote server, which includes executing some applications. The `.bashrc` file on the remote machine defines the `PATH` variable so that these applications are under it.

But when I tried to use `ssh <host> <command>` , it seems that `.bashrc` was not loaded. `ssh <host> 'echo $PATH'` only show a few pathes like `/usr/bin` .

What confused me even more is that, even `ssh <host> "source ~/.bashrc; <command>"` not worked. `ssh <host> 'source ~/.bashrc; echo $PATH'` still only printed a few pathes. I checked by `ssh <host> 'cat ~/.bashrc'` and confirmed that this file does contains all the `PATH` definition, which was not affected in the environment where  the command executed.

Comment: NB running `ssh <host> "echo $PATH"` would echo your path on the local system, not the remote system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after two hours of troubleshooting, I finally find the problem. It is because the following command in the beginning of `.bashrc` .

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

This prevents anything after that being executed in the environment of `ssh <host> <command>` .

If you have a similar issue try checking the beginning of the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: This is one reason *not* to set environment variables in `.bashrc`. Put them in your login-shell configuration, and let any other non-login interactive shells inherit the variables.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now.